# omnifaces UnmappedResourceHandler prevent primefaces dynamic image loading

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, omnifaces, unmappedresourcehandler

i'm using Omnifaces (GREAT LIBRARY) in my project.
It's a jsf 2 project with primefaces 4 library, running on JBoss 7.2.
I've used the `<p:graphicImage />` for loading an image from db. 
I've found the code on internet and it's working correctly.

The problem comes when i activated the `UnmappedResourceHandler` of omnifaces on my project.
After activate, the handler is working ok, i can access to (other) image inside my resources by name from css.
But this handler active, the loading of the image in the `<p:graphicImage />` isn't working anymore.
Debugging the code, i can only see 1 request for the content (without unmappedresourcehandler the request are 2).

Is there any workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Problem is understood. Will fix it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has been fixed. The `UnmappedResourceHandler` incorrectly expected that `ResourceHandler#createResource()` would return `null` on those kind of resources, so that it could delegate the call to the wrapped resource handler. However, it didn't return `null` and ultimately an empty resource body was written to the response.

It's fixed by checking if the request parameter `ln` equals "primefaces" and if the request parameter `pfdrid` is not `null`. The `UnmappedResourceHandler` will then delegate the call to the wrapped resource handler, which would be the `PrimeResourceHandler`.

The changes are visible in commit [8abfb8a](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/8abfb8a1695b86d8e8d5496b93596a40aa3420f0) and are available as per [today's 1.8 snapshot](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/1.8-SNAPSHOT/).